# Replacing specific elements of a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I've a nested list L generated by:

```
L=Tuples[{{1, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {n, n}]
```

For instance, an *element* of this list is:

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{0,1\} & \{1,1\} \\
 \{0,1\} & \{1,1\} \\
\end{array}
\right).$

Now, for each element of the list $s$, consider for instance the two     elements in positions $\{s,1,1,1\}$ and $\{s,2,1,1\}$, in other words the two $0$ in the example above. I'm able to extract those element using:

```
L[[s]][[All, 1]][[All, 2]]
```

which delivers $\{0,0\}$.

Here is the question. How do I replace, for all elements of $s$, the sub-elements in those two positions with a new vector, say ${0,1}$?

Note that the example above the element $s$ of $L$ would now look as:

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{0,1\} & \{1,1\} \\
 \{1,1\} & \{1,1\} \\
\end{array} 
\right).$

I have tried to use

```
L[[s]][[All, 1]][[All, 2]]={0,0}
```

but this returns error

> Part specification PR[[1,1,All,All,1]] is longer than depth of object.

I've had no better luck using ReplaceParts.

Comment: (when I try to post the latex code for the matrix I'm asked to indent it as if it were code)

Comment: btw your above code `L[[s]][[All, 1]][[All, 2]]` should deliver `{1,1}` and not `{0,0}`

Comment: yes you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a single [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part) command:

```
L=Tuples[{{1,1},{0,0},{1,0},{0,1}},{2,2}];
L[[205]]

L[[205, All, 1, 1]] = {a, b};
L[[205]]
```

{{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}}}

{{{a, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{b, 1}, {1, 1}}}

Comment: thanks, this looks similar to Ali's answer

Answer (score 0):

```
L = Tuples[{{1, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {2, 2}];
Position[L, {{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}}}];
(*{{205}}*)
L[[205]]
(* {{{0,1},{1,1}},{{0,1},{1,1}}}*)

L[[205]][[All, 1]][[1]] = {0, 1}; (* here we replace *)

L[[205]]
(* {{{0,1},{1,1}},{{1,1},{1,1}}} *)
```

Comment: @Bastiani, please have a look at this

Comment: thanks again. this is working. i just now need to iterate over all tuples. what i don't get is why you assign the value susing L[[205]][[All, 1]][[1]] = {0, 1} but you call the values using L[[205]][[All, 1]][[All,1]]